# How to push and pop values from this data-structure: var x = [{value: 30, color: "red" }]

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Written in `Javascript`:

```
var data =
 [
  {
    value: 30,
    color: "blue"
  }
 ]
```

I want to push and remove some values from it.

I tried:

```
data.push (10, "red")
data.push (111, "green")
data.push (1112, "blue")

console.log (data)
console.log (data[0].value)
console.log (data[1].value)
```

which resulted in:
`qml: [[object Object],10,red,111,green,1112,blue]`
`qml: 30`
`qml: undefined`

The first value present by default in the structure is not shown in console with first print.
I am not able to see the value of the first pushed item with third print.

Comment: @Cerbrus have edited it. now reopen please.

Comment: `data` is an array. How is it supposed to know you want to push an object to it, when you're just pushing a string and a number? You're going to have to push the actual object, instead:  `data.push({ value: val, color: 'color'})`.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks for the answer. Why have you not opened the question yet? Isn't it different? Is push method shown somewhere in that linked thread?

Comment: Most of the methods used to access arrays of objects are described in that other question. As such, I think it's a good idea to keep the link for future visitors.

Comment: @Cerbrus pushing method is not shown there. You can keep the link in this thread and atleast open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should push new values like this :

data.push({value : 10, color: 'green'}).

Your JS data is an array of object so when you want to push a new value into it, you need to push an object using the syntax `{ field1: value1 ... }`

You also can write a function the job for you :

```
function add_value(data,v,color) {
   data.push({value : v, color : c});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `data` contains an `object` as it's items, so I would assume you'd want to do something like this if you were going to push to the array:

```
data.push({value : 10, color: 'red'});
```